# Functional derivative for the same function expressed in different coordinates

Tags: derivatives

This question arises when I'm reading section "3.3.1 Minkowski Space" of page 16-17 of the following document: http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnCardy/qft/qftcomplete.pdf

On page 17, they took a functional derivative of Z[J] with respect to iJ to obtain an expression for G<sup>(0)</sup>(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>).  We're supposed to take derivatives with respect to J(x), but on page 17 the document took derivatives with respect to J(x'), where x<sub>0</sub>=ix<sub>0</sub>' (the subscript 0 indicates the first element of x; the other elements remain equivalent).

Is the results the same or did the document made a mistake?

Note: The definition of functional derivative the document is using is a delta function as the test function, as explained in section 4 of the following Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Using_the_delta_function_as_a_test_function